# cant downgrade database from version 2 to 1 in android

Tags: android, database

I m in little bit trouble. 
I have set the database data version as 2 also reinstall the application after uninstalling in my app and also tried to name it to 3 but the issue isn't resolved.please help me. I am using database .db file in my application.

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

But getting following exception as below everytime:

```
"cant downgrade database from version 2 to 1"
```

Please needed quick help....

Hope I will get positive answer..

Comment: Solved at all and completed it

Comment: Then either accept the answer if it helped or add a comment (or edit your question) to let others do not waste their and our time if they'd face same issue

Comment: Pass the query like these:                                                         Cursor cursor = db.query("Table name", new String[]{"Table Field"},null, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 2):

Android does not offer database downgrade mechanism same way it does with upgrades.

So you either live with that version number (which is just a number to let your app know db schema is up to date or no, it's nothing more). or you shall export your db content to i.e. SD card, tell user to completely remove your app (so db is also removed). then user shall install freshly your app, which would check for db backup on sd card, import it and delete or flag imported).

Still, not sure why you bother that so much - it's just version number.